# sql query for the fetching back the drop-down list selected option

Tags: html, mysql, css

I have drop down list in my website and the options are stored in database in a separate table and fetched back to drop down list. Now whenever I select any option from drop down list the value of option is stored in a main table. Now how do I fetch back the selected option from the database to website?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some more detail? I assume that when the user loads the page you want the dropdown menu to display the same value it had the last time they logged in or something like that?

If such be the case, you need a few things. To start with your body tag needs an onload function that will get called when the page is loaded:

```
<body onload="dosomething()">
```

In your javascript dosomething() function you will make an ajax call to the back end which will probably be a php script.

This script will fetch the value from mysql and return it.

Your ajax code will have an onreadystatechange() function which will receive the response from the back end and do something like

```
document.getElementById('foo').value=whatevercamebackviaajax
```

Written off the top of my head, and somewhat vague, but I or somebody could probably do better with a bit more information.

You need to add javascript to your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can see the scenario where we get the option for one single user from the database so that it will be easy for understanding and you shall make your own code if you need to customize it.

**PHP method:**

> Scenario: Keep Selected the `login username` is equal to the `clientname` in select tag.

```
<?php
$select="SELECT * FROM TABLE where id='".$_GET['uid']."'"; 
// here `uid` is the logged in user id
$q=mysqli_query($conn,$select) or die($select);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($q);
?>

<select name="sclient" id="sclient" class="reginput"/>
<option value="">Select Client</option>
<?php
$sel="select * from user where type='client'";
$que=mysqli_query($conn,$sel) or die($sel);
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($que))
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $res['login_name']; ?>"<?php if($row['clientname']==$res['login_name']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $res['login_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

**Parameters:**

1. `$conn` - Connection Variable to DB. Db Connectivity using `mysqli`